# npm rull dev rollup module not found

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, tailwind-css, vite

this is the error i am facing
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Mern job portal\my-project> npm run dev

```
> my-project@0.0.0 dev
> vite

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
             ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Mern job portal\my-project\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-x64-msvc\rollup.win32-x64-msvc.node
at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:18)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Mern job portal\my-project\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:60:48)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
```

code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}`

Node.js v18.18.2

my node version is 18.18.2 and i used the command npm create vite@latest my-project -- --template react to create the folder my-project in which i have my node_modules

i tried removing the module and reinstalling it but it was of no use

Answer (score -1):

It says module not found here. Try to find the module.

***return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));`***

Comment: the module is already present in the node modules